# Application of the the Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> **Problem.** Consider the function
>   $$F(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2}e^{-tx}dx,\quad t>0.$$
>   Show, using the Dominated Convergence Theorem, that $F$ is differentiable for every $t > 0$, with
>   $$F'(t) = - \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{3}e^{-tx},\quad \forall t>0.$$

This problem is a particular case of Differentiating under the integral sign, however, this result has not been proven so far. The only result I can use is the Dominated Convergence Theorem (and those before him, of course).

We are considering the Lebesgue measure.

**My approach.**
Let $(t_{n})$ be any sequence such that $t_{n} \to t$ and $t_{n} \neq t$ for each $t$.
$$\frac{F(t_{n}) - F(t)}{t_{n} - t} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\underbrace{\frac{x^{2}e^{-t_{n}x} - x^{2}e^{-tx}}{t_{n} - t}}_{\varphi_{n}(x)}dt.$$

For each $x$ we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\varphi_{n}(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^{2}e^{-t_{n}x} - x^{2}e^{-tx}}{t_{n} - t} = -x^{3}e^{-tx}.$$

If $g$ is a integrable function such that $|x^{3}e^{-tx}| \leq g(x)$ for each $x$, by the Means Value Theorem
$$\varphi_{n}(x) = \frac{x^{2}e^{-t_{n}x} - x^{2}e^{-tx}}{t_{n} - t} = -x^{3}e^{-cx}$$
for some $c \in (t,t_{n})$. So, $|\varphi_{n}(x)| \leq g(x)$. Thus, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\varphi_{n}(x)dt = \int_{0}^{\infty}-x^{3}e^{-tx}dt = F'(t)$$

Is this correct? Moreover, how can I find $g$?

Comment: I'm not good at this, but I know that $F(t)$ is the Laplace transform of $x^2$, if that helps.

Comment: That's correct, just take $g(x) = x^3 e^{-t x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find a suitable function $g$, we can use the fact that the sequence $(t_n)$ consists of positive numbers and converges to a positive number hence there exists a positive $\delta_0$ such that for all $n$, $\delta_0\leqslant t_n$. This guarantees that for all $x \gt 0$, $e^{-cx}\leqslant e^{-\delta_0x}$ hence we can define 
$$
g(x):=x^3e^{-\delta_0x}.
$$
This work since this function is integrable and $\delta_0$ depends only on the sequence $(t_n)_n$.